# Is it possible to define dynamic types for an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following class:

```
export class GenericIndex<T> {
  private indexableAttribute: keyof T

  public constructor(indexableAttribute: keyof T) {
    this.indexableAttribute = indexableAttribute
  }

  public addToIndex(someObject: T): void {
    const indexValue: string = someObject[this.indexableAttribute]
  }
}
```

The goal here is to allow objects of any type to be indexed, provided they have an `indexableAttribute` of `string` type.  Is there a way to specify that the interface `T` can be any object with some attribute `indexableAttribute` with a `string` value?

Currently, the code throws a

```
Argument of type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Comment: It looks like you're indexing into an `object` (e.g. `someObject` in your snippet). In such a case, the key _must always_ be a `string` because JS will `toString()` the key, and then store the relevant value against it. If you want a non-string key, consider looking into the `Map` class.

Comment: It's not that I need to enforce that the key is a `string`, I need to enforce that the value the key references is a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expanded on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008000/780265:

```
type IsValidAtrribute<Base, Condition> = Extract<keyof Base, {
  [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]
> & string
```

The `& string` is mostly for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The following might be what you need.

```
// The trick is to use this utility type
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;

export class GenericIndex<T> {
    private indexableAttribute: keyof SubType<T, string>;

    public constructor(indexableAttribute: keyof SubType<T, string>) {
        this.indexableAttribute = indexableAttribute;
    }

    public addToIndex(someObject: T): void {
        // Unfortunately I still have to convert the value to `any` here,
        // but our utility type can guard against misusage of our constructor
        const indexValue: string = someObject[this.indexableAttribute] as any;
    }
}

// Let's give it a try...

interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

new GenericIndex<Test>("a"); // OK
new GenericIndex<Test>("b"); // Not OK
```

Check out this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=39#code/PTAEBUAsFNQFwE4EsDGBrUSDO8D2oBXLWOSbQuJAGyTgE946AHaAKHpdAGUCAjcZtAA8AIQCGxADSgAwrgB2AE1pIFAPlABeUAAVUaUROjSA3q1AXQAbQDS0Bknmg093ADNQ44gF0AXJ6Nbe29QaAAPOGglHDklFQVQAH5QOwZ-eWgAN2gEVgBfKxc6dwCfNQBuVlZwplwEOFAUKgkcAHEonNQASSVwoXANM0tQJmRMsUjMXrCxXipoAEE4RCReAkj-IpKefkF+6SwV+QBzCqrhpj4aFEaFQ4QCFDg6gApHRXDZ+aWVtY3nVweHYCFj7UD3RynACUoCGw0spGwADp3p85otlsg-rBtKiZuiflj1tBKsM8udLJc5qhQGJFIpwLgeh8wi8sLgALbQADyvAAVtAnv5wFD-JlcEhFLDzPCLCBQABVeRuOpwAjyCbQKgMLrgyhUKigSBibJ4W7ybL1eAwUDjKgEEj4AAGYnkdCdRpyxhlsvlf1AuAICAo1FoDA4sBQrtAxwIYgQUrExzEjkOoA52CISdgJUDwZQd0Qj2euVlFgL8jTeIAamJ7dB-BCTlpwZyefzBXArIisCjpl8Mb9iSEJLS3aTLOTyax5QAZaBwADkOGOSFNtFp8AQdCRu6qjkiCDcYhQsHA0DTcIsYkbR2OE4svHSBA5vBylWnGQA7qB2hlkCgzJ9OehxqC8ABEYjgVC5SgPK3I2Kw36-h0AFAWE-QXnAYHgbw0GwfKAByuANAhQA)

Answer (score 1):

The only property this class cares about is the indexable one. So `T` can extend a type that has this one property only. It may have other properties, and the generic parameter will remember those, but you can treat this object as having just one string key. And since typescript needs to know the name of that key, it also must be generic.

So we have a string `K` that can be any string, but the object type must have a string at property `K` to pass type checking.

All this means that something like this works:

```
export class GenericIndex<T extends { [key in K]: string }, K extends string> {
    private indexableAttribute: K

    public constructor(indexableAttribute: K) {
        this.indexableAttribute = indexableAttribute
    }

    public addToIndex(someObject: T): void {
        const indexValue: string = someObject[this.indexableAttribute]
    }
}

// Good:
new GenericIndex<{ a: string, b: number }, 'a'>('a')

// Type '{ a: string; b: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ b: string; }'.
new GenericIndex<{ a: string, b: number }, 'b'>('c')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4HFgDthQCWCAkrgCagA8AKnKDHuZgN5wDaA1sAJ5yG44AaQC6ALjhoYRXAHM4AXwA0w+iEYVMUmbIB8cFgCg4JuGCIA3FI34VQKAEZJgAQRjTCDgK6MJQw8amYF5OxIgQuNpeCDDQABQClCCOzm4e3r7CAJQGgaamMAAWhGgAdIn2Tq7uRBnAcAC8tkkp1ek+wHmKAfnBoQhwKOTkNBBkSXFoEAC2wADyDgBWwDESNFkSFhCE5Ln5+QgRUs2gAGooSF7AEtoC8k1TswvLMexFJeV2yVVptR0iXQUhiBhgA9KDsBAIOQxIZ8AB3bB4AjEcbUNgoG4eOQqBwSXBeaYOAiKFQAchQZN0cQpZKypSGIzGXziGIkFIcCDJuIkAEYAEwAZkUWQC4LgAFFwCt4AQoNA0LCEUj8ERSF8qGzJNjZDy4ASiSTlHAyQ4qTSzfTGaM0SBWYN2Y4uXqBcKFFkgA)

Now `const indexValue: string = someObject[this.indexableAttribute]` works because we only know that `T` has one key `K`, which is a string. So `T[K]` must be a string.

---

But as you can see there is a downside here. With generics either all parameters are inferred, or they are all explicit. You can't make one explicit, and infer another.

So the indexable attribute `K` cannot be inferred because `T` cannot be inferred. And `T` cannot be inferred because it's not part of the constructor.

So you could fix this with the following constructor:

```
public constructor(indexableAttribute: K, objects?: T[]) {
    this.indexableAttribute = indexableAttribute

    if (objects) {
        for (const object of objects) {
            this.addToIndex(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Which would now let you do the following:

```
// Inferred:
new GenericIndex('a', [{ a: 'abc', b: 123 }])
new GenericIndex('a', [] as { a: string, b: number }[] )

// Or omit the second argument and be the same as above.
new GenericIndex<{ a: string, b: number }, 'a'>('a')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=20&ssc=86&pln=20&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4HFgDthQCWCAkrgCagA8AKnKDHuZgN5wDaA1sAJ5yG44AaQC6ALjhoYRXAHM4AXwA0w+iEYVMUmbIB8cFgCg4JuGCIA3FI34VQKAEZJgAQRjTCDgK6MJQw8amYF5OxIgQuNpeCDDQABQClCCOzm4e3r7CKhAOAFbAMWgA-BI07CIAlAaBpqYwABaEaAB0ifZOru5EGcBwALy2SSmd6T7AAbW1hABmcHE5+YVVRpOrcNPQcwgRUnALBfAQs-tL1WvncA1NzSjk5DQQZEnzeQcVNRcKH7VfPxNBISQYVu90edhAcTQEAAtsAAPKvGKlCoSCwQQjkM5rbaReBtEAANRQSC8wAk2gE8gGUNhCMWMHYVxa+OGaW6YxEHy+X0MAHpedgIBByGJDPgAO7YPAEYhPahsFDkjxyFQOCS4LzQhwERQqADkKD1ujiBr1FRudwecohCokBocCD1qokAEYAEwAZkU7z5AoAouADvQoFBoGhRRKpfgiKRwVRbZJlbJnXANVqdco4HqHEaTY7zSCreC4mwRVnHI6U+6vQoffy4GRpgQoMARWLgJKcNHZcXTSp2An7ZW4Gq4NXFJULaDrSW4Iryw6nSPXZ7ve3O9KYzO+xwRHPWHOlToU2ntVBFOU4AXLWDnoOK0vR+Pa0A)